# Twilio Client for incoming Calls

Tags: php, twilio

How to get notified in Twilio CLient for incoming calls? 
I'm exploring Twilio Client I'm new about this.

```
    $capability = new ClientToken($TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, $TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
    $capability->allowClientOutgoing($TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID);
    $capability->allowClientIncoming($identity); //what to do in this?..
    $token = $capability->generateToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
 // do something here... 
}
```

This is the function you can use to get notified on incoming calls